# Mark interpolated NaN points in Pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

When I use interpolation (or `fillna`, or any other method of generating some fake data) in Pandas, I would like this to show in my plots. Ideally, I would like to use a different marker for these points in the plot. For regular points I want to use filled circles (`'o'`), for fake data I want to use crosses (`'x'`).

Of course, I would like to do this with a nice Pythonic oneliner.

One further complication is that I want to use the `subplots` option in the plot function to plot all my columns at once. I'm hoping manipulating the subplots with Matplotlib voodoo is not necessary, though at this point that's the only option I can think of.

The data I'm using is something like the following (put into file 'meterstanden.ssv'):

```
datum       tijd   gas[m^3]   electra1[kWh] electra2[kWh]  water[m^3]
2015-03-06  09:00  4000.318   10300         9000           300.0
2015-03-24  20:10  4020.220   -             10003          -
2015-08-02  11:15  4120.388   10500         11000          350.5
```

And here is the script I'm using to process it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("meterstanden.ssv", delim_whitespace=True,
                   parse_dates=[[0, 1]], index_col=0, na_values=['-'])

df.interpolate(method='time').plot(subplots=True, layout=(2, 2),
                                   figsize=(14, 10), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

I want the `-` entries in the table to be plotted with cross-markers.

Comment: I haven't been able to replot over the same subplots/layout - for some reason it always makes a new figure..

Answer (score 5):

I can't come up with pythonic one-liner, but maybe this will do. (With a scatter plot you'd have some more options, like using the `s` kwarg, although I'm not sure it's ultimately any better than this solution.)

```
np.random.seed(123)
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'x':np.random.choice([1,2,np.nan],20),
                  'y':np.random.choice([3,4,np.nan],20) },
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-1-1',periods=20) )
```

I think that regardless of the exact approach it will be necessary to set up two dataframes which differ with respect to inclusion of the imputed values.  I'll do it like this.

```
mask=df.isnull()
df=df.interpolate(method='time')
imputed=df[mask]
```

Then it's just a matter of overlaying two line plots.  One is done normally but the second is with no lines and only includes the imputed values.  You don't care about the connecting lines from the imputed values, but you do want to see the points, so you give them a distinguishing marker.  I'm using 'o' instead of 'x' as you requested because the 'o' displays a little more clearly but you can change that, of course.

```
for c in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df[c])
    plt.plot(imputed[c],linestyle='',marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

You could also consider using the line color to convey information about what parts of the graph are based on imputed values.  There are several ways you might do this, here's one.

```
not_imp=df[~mask]

for c in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df[c],color='r')
    plt.plot(not_imp[c],color='b',marker='o')
    plt.plot(imputed[c],color='r',marker='d',linestyle='')
    plt.show()
```

So what is happening here is that the blue (circle) markers indicate real (not imputed) values and blue lines connect real to real.  Red (diamond) markers indicate imputed values and red lines connect imputed values to other imputed values or to real values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems this is indeed the best way to do the different markers, thanks. I still need to do Matplotlib magicks for the subplots, though.

Comment: @egpbos  Yeah, sorry I couldn't see how to combine the two but hopefully this is a good start.  If I figure something out later, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. As far as I have found, there is not a neat way to utilize the `layout=` and `subplots=` options in the `pandas.DataFrame.plot` function to do what you want. [The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-missing-data) don't say too much in this regard.

## My attempt

First I made some test data

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'D':np.random.random(150) , 
                        'A':np.random.random(150),
                        'B':np.random.random(150), 
                        'C':np.random.random(150)})
df1[ df1 > 0.8] = np.nan
df1[ df1 < 0.1] = '-'
```

Next you want to fill the `NaN` so you can plot them, I did this by making a separate dataframe, with the original `NaN` values set to some value, and everything else set to `NaN`:

```
# fill na with a lucky number
df2 = df1.fillna( 0.777)
df2[df2 != 0.777] = np.nan
```

For the `'-'` markers, I set them to some value (you might want to set them to the average of the respective column, or something), and then set everything else to `np.nan`:

```
#Similarly,  fill the '-' with another number
df3 = df1.copy()
df3[ df3 != '-'] = np.nan
df3[ df3 == '-'] = 0.5

# finally convert non-numerics to np.nan
df1[ df1=='-'] = np.nan
```

Now, I attempted to plot each of these dataframes

```
# make plot options for each dataframe
opts =  ({ 'marker':'o' ,'color':'b', 'title':'data' },
        {'marker':'d', 'color':'g','title':'NaN' }, 
        {'marker':'x', 'color':'r','title':'"-" values'} )
dfs  = (df1,df2,df3 )
for opt,df in zip( opts, dfs ):
    df.plot( subplots=True, layout=(2,2), **opt)
plt.show()
```

this made the following 3 figures
[image]
[image]
[image]
, which is not quite what you want.

## Alternate method using pylab directly

Taking the original dataframes above, you can utilize pylab directly (ever so slightly) to accomplish something that you might like:

```
cols     = ['D','A','B','C'] # the cols you want to plot
fig,axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2) # ncols*nrows should =len(cols)
axs     = [ ax for sublist in axs for ax in sublist]  # flatten the axs array

for ax,col in zip( axs, cols):
    df1[col].plot( ax=ax,marker='o',label='data')
    df2[col].plot( ax=ax,marker='d', label='NaN')
    df3[col].plot( ax=ax,marker='x',label='-')
    ax.set_title(col)
plt.show()
```

This produced the following[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment there is no way to answer my question satisfactorily. Based mainly on the answer by JohnE, here's what I eventually did (this is too much low-level Matplotlib imho, which is why I don't consider this or the other answers given so far an answer to my question):

```
df = pd.read_table("meterstanden.ssv", delim_whitespace=True,
                   parse_dates=[[0, 1]], index_col=0, na_values=['-'])

missing = df.isnull()
df_ip = df.interpolate(method='time')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 10))
ax = ax.flatten()

for ix, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    df_ip[col_name].plot(marker=None, ax=ax[ix])
    df_ip[~missing][col_name].plot(marker='o', color='green', lw=0, ax=ax[ix])
    df_ip[missing][col_name].plot(marker='s', color='red', lw=0, ax=ax[ix])
    ax[ix].set_title(col_name)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but the following works:

```
missing_df = df_ip.mask(df.notnull())
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where would you put that line? And then how do you create the full plot?